# Swap neighbouring elements in std::list

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, containers

I want to change places of neighbouring elements in the `std::list`

Example of the list and values

```
A B C D E F G
3 2 1 2 1 3 2
```

What I expect to receive after sorting:

```
A B D C F E G
3 2 2 1 3 1 2
```

So, simple `A > B` = nothing to do, but `C < D` = swap them and go to `E` comparison.

I have no idea about how to swap neighbor elements.

So, I want to move forward to 1 step `good` elements

Comment: either `splice()` or `std::swap(*itr1, *itr2)` or `erase()/insert()`

Comment: `std::list` is not very lucky choice for sorting

Comment: good, but the problem also with the iterator on the while circle. after `swap` it will point to prev-prev element.

Comment: @LihO what is the better choice?

Comment: @abrahab: `std::vector`, it's much better when elements are stored within continuous block of memory

Comment: @LihO thnanks, maybe, but my program already use `list` and I store this list at the sessions (size) and use `splice` already to insert elements to the certain positions of my `list`. seems `vector` are not good at it.

Comment: You should have a look at [std::iter_swap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap)

Comment: @LihO `std::list::sort` is perfectly capable of efficiently sorting lists.

Comment: @LihO The OP doesn't want to sort the list. He wants to walk over list and swap adjacent elements if some condition holds. This works perfectly fine on `std::list`.

Comment: Thanks all for your attention to my problem. Now I need some time to test all solutions and find the best one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do this by using two iterators:

```
void biswap(std::list<int> &l)
{
    if (l.size() < 2)
        return;
    auto it2 = l.begin();
    auto it1 = it2++;
    auto e = l.end();
    for (;;)
    {
        if (*it1 < *it2)
            std::swap(*it1, *it2);
        it1 = it2++;
        if (it2 == e)
            return;
        it1 = it2++;
        if (it2 == e)
            return;
    }
}
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/29N4FC)

Note: in case you're not using C++11 and thus calling `size()` might present a significant overhead, you can replace it with this (and of course replace all usage of `auto` with explicit types):

```
void biswap(std::list<int> &l)
{
    auto it2 = l.begin();
    auto e = l.end();
    if (it2 == e)
        return;
    auto it1 = it2++;
    if (it2 == e)
        return;
    for (;;)
    // ... the rest as before
}
```

Comment: thanks, nice, it's do what I want on the task, but seems need to be aware that `.size()` of the list can be linear on execution time (performance issue for big list), and maybe better to test the list something other to start? Also thanks for the wonderful test platform at your live example.

Comment: @abrahab In C++11 (which I used in the code), `std::list::size()` is guaranteed to be constant time. Of course, it's trivial to replace it with two `end()` tests - I will edit it in.

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard algorithm `std::adjacent_find` to find a pair of elements for which first < second and then swap them.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
   std::list<int> l = { 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2 };

   for ( int x : l ) std::cout << x << ' ';
   std::cout << std::endl;

   auto it = std::adjacent_find( l.begin(), l.end(), std::less<int>() );

   if ( it != l.end() ) std::swap( *it, *std::next( it ) );

   for ( int x : l ) std::cout << x << ' ';
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The output is

```
3 2 1 2 1 3 2 
3 2 2 1 1 3 2
```

Or if you want to process all such situations when first < second then you can use the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> l = { 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2 };

    for ( int x : l ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::list<int>::iterator it = l.begin();

    while ( ( it = std::adjacent_find( it, l.end(), std::less<int>() ) ) != l.end() )
    {
        std::swap( *it, *std::next( it ) );
    }

    for ( int x : l ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The output is

```
3 2 1 2 1 3 2 
3 2 2 1 3 2 1
```

Comment: This would also compare `B` and `C`, which the OP apparently doesn't want to do.

Comment: @Angew I am not sure that he wants to compare only C and D. I think he wants to order the list.

Comment: Well, your output doesn't match the OP's desired output as stated in the Q.

Comment: @Angew It is not clear what he wants because he already updated his post. Nevertheless I showed some methods that he can use.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions of the method, it can be useful, but after some testing I found that it's not suitable for my own task. and @Angew is right. You solution order whole list and it can move some elements for more then 1 step from the original position. `std::list<int> l = { 2, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, _1_, 3, 2, 3, 4 };` on this row underlined `1` moved to the end of the list, ( 4 steps from original), but thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This gives the desired result and it switches the comparison for "good" elements, exactly as you asked:

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename Type>
void print(const list<Type> & l)
{
    for (auto element : l) cout << element << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    list<int> l = {3,2,1,2,1,3,2}; 

    print(l);

    auto it = l.begin(); 
    while(std::next(it) != l.end())
    {
        if (*it < *std::next(it))
        {
            std::swap(*it, *std::next(it)); 
            ++it; 
        }
        ++it; 
    } 

    print(l); 

    return 0;
}
```

Executing results with:

```
3 2 1 2 1 3 2 
3 2 2 1 3 1 2
```

Comment: very good solution and it's also suotable for my task. seems it's also "swap next element if its not swaped" nice!

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't have C++11 support, simple C++03 solution using 2 iterators could be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

void swapNeighbours(std::list<int>& l) {

    std::list<int>::iterator it = l.begin();
    std::list<int>::iterator prev = it++;
    while (prev != l.end() && it != l.end()) {

        // swap if needed:
        if (*prev < *it)
            std::swap(*prev, *it);

        // move 2 times forward:
        if (++it == l.end())
            break;
        prev = it++;
    }
}
```

Then (based on your example) if you do:

```
void print(const std::list<int>& l) {
    std::list<int>::const_iterator i;
    for (i = l.begin(); i != l.end(); ++i) {
        std::cout << *i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    std::list<int> l;
    l.push_back(3); l.push_back(2); l.push_back(1); l.push_back(2);
    l.push_back(1); l.push_back(3); l.push_back(2);

    print(l);
    swapNeighbours(l);
    print(l);
}
```

then for the:

```
A B C D E F G
3 2 1 2 1 3 2
```

there will be following comparisons: `A < B`? (no) `C < D`? (yes, swaps) `E < F`? (yes, swaps too) yielding the output:

```
3 2 2 1 3 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is a pairwise traversal and swap elements if the first one is less than the second then you can e.g. use `std::adjacent_find` like this:

```
using std::swap;
for (auto it = std::begin(l); it != std::end(l); it = std::adjacent_find(it, std::end(l), std::less<int>{})) {
    swap(*it, *std::next(it));
}
```

This will cause the list of numbers `3 2 1 2 1 3 2` to be arranged as:

```
3 2 2 1 3 2 1
```

**But**, this is *not* the same as your expected result `3 2 2 1 3 1 2` and I don't undestand why you do not  want to swap the last pair `1 2` like the others?

If what you want is an *erratic* pattern for sorting then there can be no simple solution. Instead you must use special handling of individual elements.

Comment: maybe your solution will be also useful (need some more testing on the real app ), but on the original idea I don't want to swap the last pair, because one element of this pair already swapped. So, if we will swap it - element `E` will change the position 2 times. So, two steps from the original position maybe to much for my task.